# Is there a polynomial of degree 2 such that $f (0) = 1, f (2) = 2$ and $f (3) = 2$?

Tags: polynomials

I was wondering if there exist a polynomial whith these.

I've trying, but since I only started to see polynomials I don't how to get to the correct answer

Any help?

Comment: Yes, there is. It will be a downward parabola whose peak is somewhere between $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Yes, by Lagrange interpolation

Comment: By Lagrange interpolation, between any $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ there is always a $n-1$ degree polynomial through all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.  Write your polynomial as $ax^2+bx+c$ and substitute in the values, giving
$$a0^2+b0+c=1\\a2^2+b2+c=2\\a3^2+b3+c=2$$
The first gives $c=1$, leaving you two equations in two unknowns to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is

$$P(x)=\frac{(x-2)(x-3)}{(1-2)(1-3)}\color{red}{f(1)}$$

$$+\frac{(x-1)(x-3)}{(2-1)(2-3)}\color{red}{f(2)}$$
$$+\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(3-1)(3-2)}\color{red}{f(3)}$$
$$=\frac 12(x^2-5x+6)-2(x^2-4x+3)+(x^2-3x+2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Solve the system of equations
$$f(0)=c=1$$
$$f(2)=4a+2b+1=2$$
$$f(3)=9a+3b+1=2$$ in $$a,b,c$$

Comment: You will get $$c=1,a=-\frac{1}{6},b=\frac{5}{6}$$